# How do I code it so that two alerts will pop up at once in different places?

Tags: applescript

```
repeat
display alert "Don't you dare close this button" buttons {"ok"}
if the button returned of the result is "ok" then
    display notification with title ":))))))))" subtitle "muahahahahahhh" sound name "Frog"
    display alert "Don't you dare close this button" buttons {"ok"}
    display alert "Don't you dare close this button" buttons {"ok"}
end if
end repeat
```

I don't get what I did wrong, I did two display alerts. Can someone perhaps help me with this? Thank you in advance

Comment: `display alert` is modal - the script does not continue until the alert is dismissed.  Something else such as a panel or window could be used via some AppleScriptObjC - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but…

If you got a little help from other processes, you can :

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "Finder" to display alert "Don't you dare close this button" buttons {"ok"}
    display alert "Don't you dare close this button" buttons {"ok"}
end ignoring
```

Unfortunately, the alerts are at the same place on the screen.

BTW ,  your test "`if the button returned of the result is "ok" then`" is useless since the result can't be anything else than "ok".

Comment: wait where do I put it in?

Comment: um the ignoring script doesn't work, since it only shows one message every time. two messages don't show up when i make it into a script